# Почему таймер запускается лишь один раз?

Tags: javascript, таймер, setinterval, clearinterval

Имеется следующий код:

```js
(function(){
 var doc = document;
 /*doc.onselectstart = function(){

 };*/
 doc.onselectionchange = function () {
  let {anchorNode, anchorOffset, focusNode, focusOffset} = document.getSelection();
  var btn = doc.getElementById("check");
  var bo = btn.style.opacity;
  console.log(bo);
  var timer;
  var AtoB = function () {
      console.log("AtoB");
   if (bo < 1.0) {
    bo += .05;
    if (bo > 1.0) 
     bo = 1.0;
    btn.style.opacity = String(bo);
   }
   if (bo == 1.0)
    clearInterval(timer); 
  };
  //console.log(anchorNode, anchorOffset, focusNode, focusOffset);
  var tree = [];
  var parent = anchorNode.parentElement;

  var i = 0;
  while (parent.tagName !== "BODY"){
   if (i !== 0)
    parent = parent.parentElement;
   tree.push(parent);
   i++;
  } 
  //console.log(tree);
  var ids = tree.map(function(x){
   return x.id;
  });
  var check = ids.includes("carouselMy", 0); //меняем Карусель на Ридер
  //console.log(ids);
  
  if (check && Math.abs(focusOffset - anchorOffset) > 0) {
   //timer = setInterval(AtoB, 50);
   /*timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (bo < 1.0) {
     bo += .05;
     if (bo > 1.0) 
      bo = 1.0;
     btn.style.opacity = String(bo);
    }
    if (bo == 1.0)
     clearInterval(timer); 
   }, 50);*/
  }
 };
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Литературный клуб</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="icon" href="imgs/pen_brand.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my.css">
  <style>
   body {
   background: #fefcaf;
  }
  /*.container {
   background: red;
  }*/
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>

 
  <div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark" id="nb" style="width:100%">
   <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" id="nb-brand">
    <img src="imgs/pen_brand.svg" alt="Лого (временное)" width="50" height="50">
    Литературный клуб
   </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav nav-pills nav-fill">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active bg-success" href="#" id="check">Главная</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-nb bg-warning" href="#">Регистрация</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-nb bg-warning" href="#">Авторизация</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-nb bg-warning" href="#">Форум</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
     <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search">
     <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Поиск</button>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <h3>Новые поступления</h3>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-7">
    <div id="carouselMy" class="carousel my-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
       <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
         <h5 class="card-title">Евгений Онегин (А. Пушкин)</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card body">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5"><img class="card-img" src="imgs/onegin.jpeg" alt="Card image cap"></div>
          <div class="col-7 d-flex flex-column pl-0">
           <div>Роман в стихах русского поэта Александра Сергеевича Пушкина, написанный в 1823—1830 годах, одно из самых значительных произведений русской словесности. Повествование ведётся от имени безымянного автора, который представился добрым приятелем Онегина. По словам Белинского, Пушкин назвал «Евгения Онегина» романом в стихах, поскольку в нём изображена «жизнь во всей её прозаической действительности».</div>
           <div id="card-btn" class="align-self-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" >Перейти к чтению</a></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
         
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
       <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
         <h5 class="card-title">Война и мир (Л. Толстой)</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card body">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5"><img class="card-img" src="imgs/voyna_i_mir.jpg" alt="Card image cap"></div>
          <div class="col-7 d-flex flex-column pl-0">
           <div>Роман-эпопея Льва Николаевича Толстого, описывающий русское общество в эпоху войн против Наполеона в 1805 — 1812 годах. Эпилог романа доводит повествование до 1820 года.</div>
           <div id="card-btn" class="align-self-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" >Перейти к чтению</a></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">

        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="carousel-item">
       <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
         <h5 class="card-title">Вечный зов (А. Иванов)</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card body">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5"><img class="card-img" src="imgs/vechny_zov.jpg" alt="Card image cap"></div>
          <div class="col-7 d-flex flex-column pl-0">
          <div>Три войны, революция, становление нового общественного строя — все это выпало на долю семьи Савельевых, выходцев из далекого сибирского села, обладателей сильных безудержных характеров. А если быть точнее, писатель описывает жизнь своих героев с начала ХХ века до 60-х годов. Трудна эта жизнь, но Савельевы умеют и любить страстно, и ненавидеть до последнего вздоха.</div>
          <div id="card-btn" class="align-self-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" >Перейти к чтению</a></div>
         </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">

        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
       <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
         <h5 class="card-title">Горе от ума (А. Грибоедов)</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card body">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5"><img class="card-img" src="imgs/gore_ot_uma.jpg" alt="Card image cap"></div>
          <div class="col-7 d-flex flex-column pl-0"><div>Комедия в стихах Александра Сергеевича Грибоедова. Она сочетает в себе элементы классицизма и новых для начала XIX века романтизма и реализма. Она описывает светское общество времен крепостного права и показывает жизнь 1808—1824 годов. Само «действие происходит… спустя десять лет после войны 1812 года, то есть в 1822»</div>
          <div id="card-btn" class="align-self-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" >Перейти к чтению</a></div>
         </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">

        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
       <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
         <h5 class="card-title">1984 (Дж. Оруэлл)</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card body">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5"><img class="card-img" src="imgs/1984.jpg" alt="Card image cap"></div>
          <div class="col-7 d-flex flex-column pl-0"><div>Роман-антиутопия Джорджа Оруэлла, изданный в 1949 году. Название романа, его терминология и даже имя автора впоследствии стали нарицательными и употребляются для обозначения общественного уклада, напоминающего описанный в романе «1984» тоталитаризм.</div>
          <div id="card-btn" class="align-self-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" >Перейти к чтению</a></div>
         </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">

        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselMy" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     </a>
     <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselMy" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     </a>
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselMy" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselMy" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselMy" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselMy" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselMy" data-slide-to="4"></li>
     </ol>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
    lorem*100
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Не могу понять причину, по которой таймер выполняется один раз.
Перепроверил на то, что это - именно **переменная**, а не функция.
Перепроверил написание методов. Без толку.
Закомментировал оба варианта, чтобы показать, что ни один из них не работает так, как мне нужно.

Comment: Добавьте в пример html и стили.

Comment: Добавил html. Сама функция в таймере успешно выполняется один раз. А вот с повтором самим - беда.

Comment: У вас bo это строка.

Comment: "Сама функция в таймере успешно выполняется один раз." - Вы заблуждаетесь. `setInterval` в Вашем коде не вызывается.

Comment: parseFloat тоже не особо помощник. При имеющемся (вроде как) элементе переводит сразу в NaN.

Comment: Я уже показал Вам, как это делается.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Огромное спасибо.

Comment: @AlexeyBely Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  var doc = document;
  doc.onselectionchange = function() {
    let { anchorNode, anchorOffset, focusNode, focusOffset } = document.getSelection();
    console.log("anchorOffset=", anchorOffset, "focusOffset", focusOffset);
    var btn = doc.getElementById("check");
    var bo = Number(btn.style.opacity) || 0;
    console.log(typeof bo, bo);
    var timer;
    var AtoB = function() {
      console.log("AtoB", typeof bo, bo);
      if (bo < 1.0) {
        bo += .05;
        if (bo > 1.0)
          bo = 1.0;
        btn.style.opacity = String(bo);
      }
      if (bo == 1.0)
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
    var tree = [];
    var parent = anchorNode.parentElement;

    var i = 0;
    while (parent.tagName !== "BODY") {
      if (i !== 0)
        parent = parent.parentElement;
      tree.push(parent);
      i++;
    }
    var ids = tree.map(function(x) {
      return x.id;
    });
    var check = ids.includes("carouselMy", 0); //меняем Карусель на Ридер

    if ( /*check &&*/ Math.abs(focusOffset - anchorOffset) > 0) {
      timer = setInterval(AtoB, 250);
    }
  };
})();
```

```html
<button id="check">CHECK</button>
<div>AAA BBB CCC</div>
```